# Raspbian/Java: Classpath and MySQL, working in Windows and not on Pi

Tags: java, sql, linux, windows, driver

I know this question has been asked/answered several times, but I still couldn't find a solution to this `ClassNotFoundException` error, because it works on my computer but not on my RasPi (on which I installed OpenJDK7).

My application uses JDBC to access a MySQL database, and that's the main problem. As has been pointed out on lots of websites ([[1]](http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2011/08/classnotfoundexception-in-java-example.html), [[2]](http://javarevisited.blogspot.sg/2012/03/jdbc-javalangclassnotfoundexception.html), [[3]](http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2011/01/how-classpath-work-in-java.html)), this is, unfortunately, a common problem.

So, I'm using the `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8.jar` as a driver. My folder structure is something like `/src/de/web/project/` I'm calling the main method via `java de.web.project.WakeOnLan` (which is the main class that starts all other classes etc.) I got the common ClassNotFound exception and therefor added the -cp parameter so I called the project via `java -cp .;mysql-connector-java-5.0.8.jar de.web.project.WakeOnLan` to add the driver to classpath.

This worked nicely on my Windows computer from command line, but now I want to push this code to my Raspberry Pi and execute it there. As I said, I installed OpenJDK7 there (using apt-get, if this should be important), used SFTP to upload the folder structure and the code to /home/pi/java/ where there is also the ejre1.7.0_10 folder (so the code is now actually in /home/pi/java/de/web/project/).

I now went back to /home/pi/java and entered `java -cp .;mysql-connector-java-5.0.8.jar de.web.project.WakeOnLan` as I did on my Windows computer, but it refuses to work (I've put the connector in any folder on the way, just in case). When I call this function, I get a long list of hints Java wants to give me which parameters are allowed for java, finally stating: `-bash: mysql-connector-java-5.0.8.jar: command not found`. I also tried to turn ".;mysql..." around to "mysql...;." which didn't work as well. If I don't include the -cp parameter, my program says "Thread started" and in the next line: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` etc., so the program does indeed start and writes "Thread started" to System.out.

For some reason, it looks like Java on the Pi ignored the second value of the classpath parameter for which I don't see a good reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might just have problem in classpath setting, there is difference for windows and linux

The classpath syntax is OS-dependent. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29) :

> Being closely associated with the file system, the command-line
>   Classpath syntax depends on the operating system. For example:
>
> on all Unix-like operating systems (such as Linux and Mac OS X), the
>   directory structure has a Unix syntax, with separate file paths
>   separated by a colon (":").
>
> on Windows, the directory structure has a Windows syntax, and each
>   file path must be separated by a semicolon (";").
>
> This does not apply when the Classpath is defined in manifest files,
>   where each file path must be separated by a space (" "), regardless of
>   the operating system.